# Dynamically evaluating code (like eval())

Tags: oz

Is it possible to evaluate code (as string or syntax list) at runtime (like eval()) in Oz? It is a dynamically typed language, so it may be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  it is possible. Take a look at the "Compiler" module: http://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/compiler/node4.html#section.api.module